# ASP.NET MVC controls don't display when using HTML helper with a type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Basically I have two html helpers that have a type of `@number` and `@date`. When I fill out my form every binds, however when I have a model that's prepopulated it doesn't have the values.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TotalGrossMonthlySales)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalGrossMonthlySales, "{0:c}", new { @type = "number", @class = "required numeric", id = "CurrentBalance" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TotalGrossMonthlySales)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessStartDate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BusinessStartDate, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control datepicker", @pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BusinessStartDate)
```

[image: The model has a value]

[image: However there nothing selected in the business start date box]

If I just remove the `@type` from both helpers, the controls work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => @Model.Trans.TransDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", type ="date" })
```